# Convert list of strings to numbers but maintain whitespace - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list-comprehension

I am trying to convert this list of strings `arr = c zza abb baa acd b ca zzz zr il` to numbers, which I did, but I'm joining them into one list which is not what I want. I want them to maintain the structure they original had (with spaces between the substrings). If I run this:

```py
a = []
for char in arr:                       # is the issue here because I'm iterating over each char?
    number = ord(char.lower()) - 96
    a.append(number)                   # what do I change here, when appending, to keep the space?
```

I get: `[3, -64, 26, 26, 1, -64, 1, 2, 2, -64, 2, 1, 1, -64, 1, 3, 4, -64, 2, -64, 3, 1, -64, 26, 26, 26, -64, 26, 18, -64, 9, 12]` and it converts the whitespaces to `-64` so if I run this I remove the `-64`.

```py
a = [x for x in a if x != -64]
```

and it returns: `[3, 26, 26, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 2, 3, 1, 26, 26, 26, 26, 18, 9, 12]`

However I still have them in one group, not keeping their original space separation. Overall, I need to sort each group of strings, but not using `sorted()` or `.sort()`, and while maintaining their sub-string groups. So I can't I need to retain the whitespace and sort the substrings (when they're in number form).

Comment: Why not directly sort each group of characters?

Comment: What's the end result that you want?

Comment: I want `c zza abb baa acd b ca zzz zr il ` -> `abb acd b   baa c   ca  il  zr  zza zzz`

Comment: im reading from a file, and needed to convert them to `int` and sort the number verison of them, then convert BACK to `str` and then push to output file. Versus just using built-in `sorted()` or `.sort()`

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to convert to integers at all, to sort each group of characters:

```
>>> s = "c zza abb baa acd b ca zzz zr il"
>>> " ".join("".join(sorted(grp)) for grp in s.split())
'c azz abb aab acd b ac zzz rz il'
```

Or if you meant sorting the groups themselves:

```
>>> " ".join(sorted(s.split()))
'abb acd b baa c ca il zr zza zzz'
```

Comment: what about when they're `['c', 'zza', 'abb', 'baa', 'acd', 'b', 'ca', 'zzz', 'zr', 'il']` and not as one string like you had in the first example? but yes, i want to sort each sub-group, like you did at the bottom.

Comment: @Christian Then you replace `s.split()` just with `l` where `l` is the list you just posted. So just `" ".join(sorted(l))`.